# Acceptable amount of slack in a timing chain with high mileage?

Tags: engine, chevrolet, ignition, timing, s10

**1995 Chevy S-10 Blazer - 4.3 L Vortec V6 (vin W with PCM)** - 230,000 miles original owner.

---

FWIW, this model car/engine does not have timing chain inspection and/or changing as part of the routine maintenance schedule like cars with timing belts.  According to GM, the timing chain is supposed to last for the "life of the engine".  However despite this, I realize that at 230,000 miles, the chain could very well be worn out and need replacement.

---

This question is a followup to [this answer](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/18225/11163).

I've been chasing down a rough idle condition, and after eliminating just about every other source of this, I've come down to slack in the timing chain.

The engine idle has improved greatly after putting the timing to factory spec (0 TDC w/ timing computer wire unplugged) and installing a brand new distributor.  However, it's still not quite there<sup>1</sup> and I'm trying to evaluate whether or not to change the timing chain.

There's no doubt that the chain is stretched out and I'm trying to accurately measure that.  Roughly, based on a visual inspection (rotating crank while looking at rotor), I'm thinking about 5-7 degrees.  This estimate already takes into account the play between the distributor/camshaft gears.  I'm trying to find a helper so I can get a more accurate measurement on the balancer itself.

When looking at the engine timing using a timing light, here are my observations under two very different conditions:

1. **The computer timing wire disconnected:** I did not expect to see any advance on acceleration from idle, yet my timing light shows a timing advance.  This model does not have counterweights or vacuum advance.
2. **The computer timing wire plugged in:** The timing mark seems to jump around. I would expect the computer to advance/retard timing smoothly with engine acceleration, not jump back & forth.

In both cases, the amount of movement is the same... visually estimated to be close to 1/2 inch.  The balancer is 6" diameter so that's roughly 10 degrees. There can only be slop/play in the distributor gear and/or timing chain that would explain the two observations above.

Obviously, any timing chain will gradually stretch/wear over time. What is an unacceptable amount of chain stretch or play?  At what point does changing the chain become critical?

1995 GM S-10 Service Manual says that if the chain has *"more than 5/8" of side to side movement"*, it should be changed.  However, if I take off the timing cover to measure this, then I might as well just change the chain.

---

**EDIT:  Following the procedure posted [on this website](http://www.misterfixit.com/chanslop.htm) from this [answer](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/18389/11163):**

As you can see in the photo below, using the timing tab built into the timing cover would not yield an accurate measurement.  So I clamped a steel plate to the power steering mount, which gave me a straight edge for making very accurate reference marks.  (*In this photo you can see that I've marked the timing groove and timing tab with white chalk*)

[image: http://s18.postimg.org/bzauk6aqh/IMG_5957.jpg]

Then following the procedure as posted in the answer, I rotated the crankshaft clockwise while observing the rotor moving.  I stopped and scratched a starting reference mark.  Then while my helper observed the rotor, I slowly turned the crankshaft counter-clockwise, stopping exactly when my helper observed movement, and I scratched another mark.  You can see these two scratch marks in the photo below.

[image]

- **Diameter of the balancer as measured by caliper**:  6.125"
- **Calculated circumference of the balancer**: 19.2422" (6.125 x π)
- 19.2422" divided by 360 degrees => 0.05345" per degree

The measured distance between the two marks is 3/16" (0.1875).

(0.1875") divided by (0.05345"/degree) => **3.508 degrees**

I repeated the procedure several times in different places on the balancer and always came up with 3/16".

---

**<sup>1</sup>EDIT 2**:

Remaining roughness in the idle was finally tracked down to a loose heat shield that was intermittently shorting out the spark plug boot for cylinder #4.

Comment: Great question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Referring to [this website](http://www.misterfixit.com/chanslop.htm):

> If all is well and there is no slack in the timing chain then you will see about three to five degrees of "reverse motion" before the distributor begins to turn.

To measure this, do the following:

- Get a socket which fits the front balancer crank shaft bolt.
- Get a breaker bar which is long enough to turn the crank using it.
- Take the distributor cap off so you can see the rotor.
- Rotate the crankshaft clockwise around until you are at Top Dead Center (TDC) for cylinder #1 (on the SBC and Chevy V6, this will be at the 0 timing mark).

**NOTE:** It is important you do not turn the crank past TDC then back (counter-clockwise) as this will mess up what you are trying to see.

- When ready, turn the crank backwards (counter-clockwise) *very slowly* until you start to see the rotor move.
- Observe on the timing tab the amount of degrees which the crankshaft has moved.
- 3-5° is normal.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It helps a lot.  However, this motor's timing tab is very primitive.  It's just a tab with a single notch in the middle representing 0 TDC.  I'll have to take a measurement in inches and then calculate the degrees of rotation.  Not a problem... I believe the balancer has a 6" diameter.

Comment: @Sparky - If you have to measure, no sense guessing on the diameter. Do all the measurements as accurately as possible, so your results can be as accurate as possible (probably goes without saying, though, lol).

Comment: Of course.  I'm not guessing.  However the balancer has a wheel attached to the front that is larger, which makes measurement difficult.  There is also not enough room without removing skid plates to get a caliper on it or wrap it with a tape.  So taking the outer diameter of the wheel and subtracting the amount it overhangs the balancer, I get 6 inches.  It's not exact, but it's within one eighth of an inch.  +/- 1/8" of diameter translates to +/- 0.001" of linear movement per degree.

Comment: Took off the accessory belt and the water pump wheel.  This gave me just enough clearance for a caliper.  The balancer is 6.125" diameter.  Measuring the amount of actual movement is going to be very difficult with any accuracy.  The timing tab and the timing mark have quite a gap between them.  Finding a solid point of reference for measuring is what I'm trying to do now.

Comment: @Sparky - Measure the distance from (after you move it) from the timing notch to the TDC indicator in the balancer. If you are moving the notch beyond the tab, that's a good indicator of *too much slack*.

Comment: Yes. That is exactly the plan. I guess what I was trying to say is the line stamped into the balancer is more towards the outside of the balancer, and the tab is on the motor. There is quite a bit of distance between the two. I'm used to the old motors where the tab was almost on top of the notch so taking the reading was very easy.  [See link for photo](http://s17.postimg.org/q787fdqz3/IMG_5956.jpg).  Since the mark and tab are so far apart, I'll just need to find a better point of reference for an accurate measurement.  http://s17.postimg.org/q787fdqz3/IMG_5956.jpg

Comment: Draw a line straight back to the cover and onto the cover. Use that as your moving (balancer) and stabile (cover) marks. Then measure after the movement.

Comment: Like you said, I'll just draw new reference lines or something... I'll figure out something so that the measurement is accurate.  Wasn't looking for a solution as much as simply trying to explain it clearly to you and the reader.

Comment: Please see my edited question for photos and calculations.  To my surprise, I am measuring 3.51 degrees of slop.  I feel better that I've done everything I can do, short of a rebuild.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Sparky - 3.5° is nothing considering the age of the chain. Good deal.

Comment: Yes, I was pretty happy to see that.

Comment: Referring to your NOTE in bold... I carefully read [the article](http://www.misterfixit.com/chanslop.htm) again and unless you have the valve cover off to visually inspect the valves on #1, there seems to be no reason to worry about not going past TDC before coming back CCW.  Just looking for chain slack, I can't see how it matters where you've started as long as you've taken out the slack before rotating back CCW.

Comment: @Sparky - It does matter. As you've stated, though, the idea is to take the slack out of the chain prior to marking the balancer & turning it CCW. TDC isn't important the way you've done it, just don't arbitrarily eliminate the slack prior to doing your measurement. Your method for the measurement seemed quite industrious. I give you credit there! My point was *do not go past the timing marks, then come back to them to get to TDC*. In your case, just crank it around CW and take up the slack. Then mark, move CCW until rotor movement, the mark again for measurement.

Comment: I guess my point was that the TDC location is not even mentioned in [the article](http://www.misterfixit.com/chanslop.htm) you've linked to.  At least not until the very last paragraph, where you have to remove the valve covers to inspect the valve movement, which is something I did not need to do since my slack measurement was good.

Comment: Ok, never-mind...  I get your point now.  You simply meant that if one is using the TDC mark as their first reference point, only get to it from the CW direction (to keep out the initial slack).